# How to merge struct fields in C

Tags: c, struct, merge

I'm curious if there is a way to merge two struct fields without having to explicitly check each field?

```
typedef struct NSPoint {
    int x;
    int y;
    int z;
} NSPoint;

NSPoint point1 = { .x = 5, .y = 4, .z = 3};

// Somewhere down the code

NSPoint point2 = { .x = 10 };

// Merge so it ends with: 
// { .x = 10, .y = 4, z = 3};

NSPoint point3 = point1 + point2;
```

Comment: I guess no. If you were the compiler, how would you do that?

Comment: What is your actual problem? If you're up to optimisation: Don't unless you **really** have a problem and can prove that is an issue. Until then, leave optimisations to your compiler.

Comment: `NSPoint point3 = { .x = point2.x, .y = point1.y, .z = point1.z};` //inside function.

Comment: Don't use identifers starting with an underscore followed by a capital letter - these are reserved for the implementation.

Comment: @Olaf Seen a similar pattern in different languages  was probably the reason me asking this... Thanks.

Comment: You don't merge fields, but add two struct object field-wise. That is a very different operation! And would you expect English and French have the same grammar/semantics just because they use the same alphabet? So why think different programming languages would?

Comment: How about `NSPoint point2 = point1; point2.x = 10;`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, this is not possible.

Once you realize that this:

```
NSPoint point2 = { .x = 10 };
```

Is semantically identical to this:

```
NSPoint point2 = { .x = 10, .y = 0, .z = 0 };
```

you'll understand why.

Comment: Thanks, totally make sense.